# In html the object tag property classid="X", how do you know what X should be. How would I find the class-id string

Tags: html, dom, properties, tags

In html the object tag property classid="X", how do you know what X should be. How would I find the class-id string.

Some of them are this long hex string. How do you know what the string should be why the long hex string which is unreadable. Is there a link to sight that maps all theses classids to what handles them.

```
    object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_object.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classid string is any string  that tells the browser how to handle the object. It refers to "the location of implementation". In most of the cases listed at your link these are ids of microsoft active X Controls and the clsid as found in the windows registry. But this could be urls as well.